# Are yeast "cold packs" really worth the extra cost?

Tags: yeast, shipping

Okay, so I understand the intent of the cold pack when shipping liquid yeast during very warm climates, but I assume that the useful cooling offered is very minimal compared to the temperature variations that might occur during transport from HBS to my house (which in my case would be a 2-3 day trip). The cost of some of the packs is minimal while others represent over half the cost of the yeast. I had always considered the cost "cheap" insurance, but the more I think about it, the more I wonder how beneficial they really are compared to their cost.

Any thoughts about this topic?

Comment: I think a cold pack would be useful for yeast health.  I would think that if someone is getting yeast shipped from a far distance it might be wort getting into learning how to effectively re-use and save yeast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are shipping only 2-3 days, I really think that the yeast loss would be minimal if shipped without the cold pack. Remember that yeast exist at ambient temperature in nature, after all :-) Any loss would be minimized by doing a starter before pitching.

Comment: This depends what you mean by ambient temperature. If ambient temperature is 40C then your yeast might not be too happy stuck in it for long periods.

Comment: 2-3 days is not a long period, even at 104F (40C). Notice that I recommended using a starter just in case. This should take care of any loss in transport.

Comment: Fair point drj.

Answer (score 3):

If you will be shipping the yeast in the back of your car, you don't need a cold pack.  Just keep the yeast in the cabin of the car and keep things comfortable for you, and the yeast will be happy.  However, I worked one summer in a UPS Warehouse outside of DC.  The trailers I worked in typically were 20-30 degrees hotter than ambient temperature (and the "wonderful" DC humidity).  When I ship yeast from NB between April 15-October 15, I ALWAYS buy one of the cooling packs.  It also helps if your yeast gets loaded onto the wrong truck and spends an extra day or two shipping to you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about liquid yeast?

I regularly order liquid yeast that goes from the UK -> Spain and I have never used a cold pack. So far, I have had no problems with this yeast.

Another option is to use dry yeast which I imagine is more robust to temperature changes since it is dehydrated.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer this as anecdotal evidence.  I did recently order 2 kits from Northern Brewer with 2 smack packs of yeast.  I ordered 2 cold packs.  I used their standard shipping, and it took about 5 or 6 days to arrive in Texas, where we were in the middle of weeks of 100+ degree weather.  The packs were no longer cold by the time our shipment arrived.

I made a starter from one smack pack immediately, and it worked out fine.  The other, which I'd refrigerated immediately, I smacked about a week later, and it never puffed up.  I suspect the prolonged exposure to the heat was the problem, but I cannot say that I know for sure.  Since then, we've decided to order dry yeast only during the summer months.